# How to get class level variable names using javaparser?

Tags: java, javaparser

I was able to get class level variable's declarations using the following code. But I only need the variable name. This is the output I get for following code - [private boolean flag = true;]

```
import com.github.javaparser.JavaParser;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.CompilationUnit;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.visitor.VoidVisitorAdapter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class CuPrinter{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // creates an input stream for the file to be parsed
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\arosh\\IdeaProjects\\Bot_Twitter\\src\\MyBot.java");

        CompilationUnit cu;
        try {
            // parse the file
            cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
        cu.accept(new ClassVisitor(), null);
}
private static class ClassVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter<Void> {
    @Override
    public void visit(ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration n, Void arg) {
        /* here you can access the attributes of the method.
         this method will be called for all methods in this
         CompilationUnit, including inner class methods */
        System.out.println(n.getFields());
        super.visit(n, arg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can probably iterate over `n.getFields()` and retrieve the name

Comment: No. I want to parse many java files and find their class level variables. So I don't know whats will be the variable name, modifier, type while iterating. I want a general way to get class level variables.

Comment: As said, `n.getFields()` will return an array of custom objects or even a whole new object. Which then can be generically iterated over

Comment: n.getFields() can be like  [private boolean flag = true;] or  [private boolean flag;] or [boolean flag = true;]. So in that case while coding how can I know which element of the array will be the variable name. For example in 1st one it is the 3rd element and in 2nd one it is the 2nd element.

Comment: What is the class-*type* of `n.getFields()`?

Comment: class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList

Comment: If I have two class level variables. I get this - [public int total;, private int sum;]

Comment: And the entries in the List are of type `String`?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: I guess you could solve that with regex. I have to try that out, give me some time ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following simple regex:

```
final String regex = "^((private|public|protected)?\\s+)?.*\\s+(\\w+);$";
```

Which then can be compiled into a `Pattern`:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

And then finally be used in a `for-loop`:

```
for(final String field : n.getFields()){
    // create a regex-matcher
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(field);

    // if field matches regex
    if(matcher.matches()){
        // get the last group -> the fieldName
        final String name = matcher.group(matcher.groupCount());
        System.out.println("FieldName: " + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AroshaMudalige You're welcome. Be aware that this only works for single fields declared like: `private MyClass someName;`. But not for multiple field declaration like: `private int x,y;`. Also `final` is not taken into account

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. If you have more than one variables in FieldDeclarations, use one more for loop inside.

```
public void visit(ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration n, Void arg) {

    super.visit(n, arg);
    for(FieldDeclaration ff:n.getFields())
    {
        System.out.println(ff.getVariable(0).getName());
    }
}
```